# how to configure aws code deploy with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, aws-code-deploy

In Jenkins, I want to deploy the code automatically when the build is success. I had installed aws code deploy plugin in Jenkins but not able to configure with Jenkins. Any idea?

Comment: The documentation is here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWS+Codedeploy+plugin and the plugin itself provides lots of inline help.

Comment: hey, Thanks for the help. I am facing one more problem here. The problem is:
I had configured MSTest plugin in jenkins, but I am not able to run the unit automation tests. Actually the project is in TFS, where the unit tests are written. I had specified all .dll's path in Jenkins but Console output says No tests to execute

Comment: Search for similar questions relating to that problem, and create a new one  if there's no existing question that covers your situation. Include details of how you're starting the test and what Jenkins console output there is.

Answer (score 0):

After building and installing the plugin, some simple configuration is needed for your project.

*Open up your project configuration

*In the Post-build Actions section, select "Deploy an application to AWS CodeDeploy"

*Application Name, Deployment Group, Deployment Config, and region are all required options.

*For authentication, there are two options. Either option requires that the associated role has, at minimum, a policy that permits codedeploy:* and s3:Put*. The plugin will pick up global credential from the jenkins instance.

Comment: hey, Thanks for the help. I am facing one more problem here. The problem is:
I had configured MSTest plugin in jenkins, but I am not able to run the unit automation tests. Actually the project is in TFS, where the unit tests are written. I had specified all .dll's path in Jenkins but Console output says No tests to execute.

Comment: While using AWS CodeDeploy plugin where to specify appspec.yml

Comment: @AshishKarpe - a bit late to the game so this is for future users who come across this. appspec.yml is going to go into the root of your Git repo like Bitbucket etc.